# Baofeng 888s sidekey (moni) don't work

Tags: baofeng

Baofeng 888s, programed with chirp, worked good but maybe at change channels during pushing moni button or something else (I don't know), don't work. I tried to change side key options by programming, but don't effect. 
When push it, no reflection. Is the side key burnt?

Comment: Can you clarify -- Is it correct that the Moni key worked great before you hit it with CHIRP and stopped working after you programmed with CHRIP? The button stopped working immediately after you flashed it with CHIRP? You may want to try Baofeng original software, or look at the manuals to reset the radio manually.